# Heatmap Cbar Adjust Color Gradient

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I try to adjust my cbar color but struggling with it :

When I use : `Center=None` I have the following bar :

[image]

And When I use `Center=0` , I have the following bar :

[image]

But it is not what I except : My goal is to have red starting at zero and being more and more red more the value is less than 0.

So the bar should look Like stuff like that :

[image]

So like this it will be more readable : Red Negative - Green Positive

**(More its Red More its negative - More its Green more it is positive)**

Below is my line of code :

```
ax = sns.heatmap(result, linewidth=0.1,cmap="RdYlGn",
cbar_kws=dict(ticks= [result.min()/2,.0,result.max()/2]),
center=None,vmin=result.min(),vmax=result.max(),robust=True,fmt="f")
```

It seems that `vmin` and `vmax` does not work as excepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a `TwoSlopeNorm` which compresses both parts differently. (The default uses symmetric coloring.)

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm
import seaborn as sns

norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=0)
result = np.random.uniform(-0.01, 0.1, (10, 10))
ax = sns.heatmap(result, linewidth=0.1, cmap="RdYlGn", norm=norm,
                 cbar_kws=dict(ticks=[result.min() / 2, .0, result.max() / 2]),
                 robust=True, fmt="f")
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap TwoSlopeNorm]

Comment: Thank you so much !! You really helped me there !